# Using Python and TKinter, how do I redraw the main screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program where the main window is divided into two sections each section has a collection of forms (simple label/input columns).  The default is 4 of these columns in the first section and 2 in the second section.  I would like the user to be able to change this ratio.  I think I have all of the programming in place to do this, I just can't get the main window to redraw with the correct structure.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I like the simplicity and idea behind your example, however, I'm modifying some legacy code and don't have the time to rewrite my layouts as definitions.  I tried to create a def that would simply do grid_columnconfig(), but that didn't work.  I've reduced the code so that it looks like what I'm working with and it is also functional.  If you change the variable 'max_pol_modules' it adjusts columns on the left versus columns on the right, so, I'm trying to change this variable through an interface widget and redraw.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

max_pol_modules = 3
max_bus_modules = 6 - max_pol_modules

tech_green = '#5E9732'
button_grey = '#666666'
grey = '#777777'

def config1():
    global max_pol_modules, max_bus_modules
    max_pol_modules = 1
    max_bus_modules = 6 - max_pol_modules
#    print max_bus_modules

#    left_frame.update()


def config2():
    global max_pol_modules, max_bus_modules
    max_pol_modules = 2
    max_bus_modules = 6 - max_pol_modules
#    print max_bus_modules


def config3():
    global max_pol_modules, max_bus_modules
    max_pol_modules = 3
    max_bus_modules = 6 - max_pol_modules
#    print max_bus_modules


def config4():
    global max_pol_modules, max_bus_modules
    max_pol_modules = 4
    max_bus_modules = 6 - max_pol_modules
#    print max_bus_modules

def about():
    box.showinfo("About GUI","GE Bus Converter and Point of Load GUI")

def bar(frame, row, span):
    "create a bar to separate a section"
    x = Frame(frame, relief=GROOVE, bd=2, width=86*(span+1), height=2)
    x.grid(row=row, column=0, columnspan=10, pady=7, sticky=S+E)
    x.grid_propagate(0)

def bar2(frame, row, span):
    "create a bar to separate a section"
    x = Frame(frame, relief=GROOVE, bd=2, width=86*(span+1), height=2)
    x.grid(row=row, column=0, columnspan=10, pady=3, sticky=S+E)
    x.grid_propagate(0)

def bar3(frame, row, span):
    "create a bar to separate a section"
    x = Frame(frame, relief=GROOVE, bd=2, width=100, height=2)
    x.grid(row=row, column=0, columnspan=10, pady=7, sticky=S+E)
    x.grid_propagate(0)

root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)

submenu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)

submenu2=Menu(submenu,tearoff=0)
submenu2.add_command(label="1 - 5", command=config1)
submenu2.add_command(label="2 - 4", command=config2)
submenu2.add_command(label="3 - 3", command=config3)
submenu2.add_command(label="4 - 2", command=config4)

submenu_help = Menu(submenu,tearoff=0)
submenu_help.add_command(label="About",command=about)


submenu.add_cascade(label="Change Configuration",menu=submenu2)

submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings",menu=submenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=submenu_help)

# display the menu
root.config(menu=menubar)

entry_wid = 6
small_font = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=8, weight='bold')
lite_font = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=9)
large_font = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=9)
heading_font = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=10, weight='bold')
button_font = tkFont.Font(family='Arial', size=8, weight='bold')
root.option_add('*font', lite_font)
root.option_add('*background', '#C2C2C4')
root.option_add('*Label.font', small_font)
root.option_add('*Entry.background', 'white')
root.option_add('*Button.font', button_font)
root.option_add('*Button.background', button_grey)
root.option_add('*Button.foreground', 'yellow')
root.option_add('*Text.background', 'white')
root.option_add('*Text.font', small_font)
root.option_add('*ScrolledText.font', lite_font) 

left_frame = Frame(root)
right_frame = Frame(root)

pol_frame = Frame(left_frame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
x = Label(pol_frame, text="POL Address", anchor=E)
x.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

x = Label(pol_frame, text="Rtrim (Kohms)", anchor=E)
x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)

x = Label(pol_frame, text="Nominal Vout (V)", anchor=E)
x.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)

bar2(pol_frame, 0, max_pol_modules)

module_address = []
module_i2c = []
module_status = []
module_resistor = []
module_vout_nominal = []
for i in range(max_pol_modules):
    # Module ID and address
    f = Frame(pol_frame)
    x = Label(f, text=i+1)
    x.grid(row=0, column=0)
    v = StringVar()
    x = Entry(f, textvariable=v, width=3, justify=CENTER)
    x.grid(row=0, column=1)
    f.grid(row=0, column=i+1, pady=8, padx=20)
    module_address.append(v)
    module_i2c.append("")
    module_status.append(0)
    # module resistor
    v = StringVar()
    x = Entry(pol_frame, textvariable=v, width=entry_wid, justify=CENTER)
    f = lambda event, module=i: change_resistor_event(event, module)
    g = lambda value, m=i, o=16: set_change(value, m, o)
    x.bind("<KeyRelease>", f, "+")
    x.bind("<KeyRelease>", g, "+")
    x.bind("<FocusOut>", f, "+")
    x.grid(row=1, column=i+1, pady=0)
    module_resistor.append(v)
    # module nominal vout
    v = StringVar()
    x = Label(pol_frame, textvariable=v, width=entry_wid-1,
          relief=SUNKEN, bg='#DDDDDD', font=lite_font)
    x.grid(row=2, column=i+1, pady=0)
    module_vout_nominal.append(v)

bus_frame = Frame(left_frame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
#x = Label(bus_frame, text="Module (address)", anchor=E)
#x.grid(row=0, column=max_pol_modules+1, sticky=E)
x = Label(bus_frame, text="Bus Conv Address", anchor=E)
x.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
config_bus = []
r = 0

#for i in range(max_pol_modules,max_pol_modules+max_bus_modules):
for i in range(max_bus_modules):
    # Module ID and address
    f = Frame(bus_frame)
    x = Label(f, text=i+5)
    x.grid(row=0, column=0)
    v = StringVar()
    x = Entry(f, textvariable=v, width=3, justify=CENTER)
    x.grid(row=0, column=1)
    f.grid(row=0, column=i+2, pady=8, padx=20)
    module_address.append(v)
    module_i2c.append("")
    module_status.append(0)


bar2(bus_frame, r, max_bus_modules) 
r += 1

# the measured values
measure_info = ["Vout (V)", "Iout (A)", "Vin (V)", "Temp (degC)"]
measures_bus = []
for mi in measure_info:
    x = Label(bus_frame, text=mi, anchor=E)
    x.grid(row=r, column=0, sticky=E)
    m = []
    for j in range(max_bus_modules):
        v = StringVar()
        x = Label(bus_frame, textvariable=v, width=entry_wid-1,
              relief=SUNKEN, bg='#DDDDDD', font=lite_font)
        x.grid(row=r, column=j+2)
        m.append(v)
    measures_bus.append(m)
    r += 1

pol_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+W)

bus_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+W)

left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)

right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

root.mainloop()
```

Edited Example where form[4] and form[5] need to be deleted.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.forms = []
        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        self.toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        button2 = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="2 columns", command=self.layout2col)
        button3 = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="3 columns", command=self.layout3col)
        button2.pack(side="left")
        button3.pack(side="left")
        self.forms_frame = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.forms_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="True", padx=2, pady=2)
        for i in range(6):
            frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.forms_frame, text="Form %s" % i)
            self.forms.append(frame)
            label = tk.Label(frame, text="Field %s" % i)
            entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=20)
            label.pack(side="left", fill="y")
            entry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.layout2col()

    def layout3col(self):
        self.forms[0].grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[1].grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[2].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[3].grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[4].grid(column=2, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[5].grid(column=2, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def layout2col(self):
        self.forms[0].grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[1].grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[2].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[3].grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")


        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to remove some forms, use `grid_remove`. It might help if you read the documentation on the grid command -- it has all the features you need to move, remove, add, widgets, and configure or reconfigure rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the grid geometry manager, you just need to use the `grid` method to place them in their new rows and columns. You may need to also call `rowconfigure` and/or `columnconfigure` to attach appropriate weights to the new rows and columns.

Here's a bit of a contrived example showing the general principle. It could be more efficient but hopefully it gives you a rough idea:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.forms = []
        self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        self.toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        button2 = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="2 columns", command=self.layout2col)
        button3 = tk.Button(self.toolbar, text="3 columns", command=self.layout3col)
        button2.pack(side="left")
        button3.pack(side="left")
        self.forms_frame = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
        self.forms_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="True", padx=2, pady=2)
        for i in range(6):
            frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.forms_frame, text="Form %s" % i)
            self.forms.append(frame)
            label = tk.Label(frame, text="Field %s" % i)
            entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=20)
            label.pack(side="left", fill="y")
            entry.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.layout2col()

    def layout3col(self):
        self.forms[0].grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[1].grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[2].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[3].grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[4].grid(column=2, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[5].grid(column=2, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def layout2col(self):
        self.forms[0].grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[1].grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[2].grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[3].grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[4].grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms[5].grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=2, sticky="ew")
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.forms_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I like the simplicity and idea behind your example, however, I'm modifying some legacy code and don't have the time to rewrite my layouts as definitions.  I tried to create a def that would simply do grid_columnconfig(), but that didn't work.  I've reduced the code so that it looks like what I'm working with and it is also functional.

Comment: After some testing, I've discovered that I can add additional columns but can't seem to remove columns no longer needed.  I've modified your code to demonstrate what I'm having a problem with.

Comment: @Stephen: You can't really remove rows because rows don't really exist as objects. What you can do, however, is reset any configuration option for a row or column so it doesn't take up space (assuming nothing is actually in that row or column). You can use `grid_size` to get how many rows and columns it thinks it has, then reset the weight to zero for all the empty rows or columns. If you have forms that need to be removed (versus moved to a different row or column) use `grid_forget`.

Comment: Well, I read through the documentation and did a little more experimenting, and the way the code is currently written there doesn't seem to be a clean way to make happen what I want to happen. Thanks for your help with this one.

Comment: @Stephen: rest assured, what you want to do is possible -- there are no limitations in Tkinter that prevent you to change a layout at runtime. Unfortunately, your description of the problem just isn't sufficient to know what the real problem is.

Comment: @Bryan:  I certainly don't think it's impossible, just improbable given my knowledge and limited time.

Answer (score -1):

You've probably already tried this, but can you call update() on your root widget?
You might also need to pack() again, first.

Comment: I have tried update on just about everything without any success.  I'm not currently using pack(), so I'm not familiar with that.  I'll take a look at pack() and see how I should integrate that.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Keep in mind, it's been about a year since I've worked with Python/TKinter, so ymmv.

Comment: Ok, did some quick research.  Didn't realize that pack() was a layout manager.  I'm currently using the grid manager.